# Cannot get javascript working to check checkbox value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html

My scenario is quite simple. I have a few checkboxes and I want to check whether they are checked or not.

Now I'm using the following:

```
        @Html.CheckBox("chkColour")<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkColourCoding" value="Colour Coding" />Colour coding<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkDoggyBars" value="Doggy Bars" />Doggy bars<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkLadderRacks" value="Ladder Racks" />Ladder racks<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkCabSliders" value="Cab Sliders" />Cab sliders<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkBrakeLights" value="Brake Lights" />Brake Lights<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkInteriorLights" value="Interior Lights" />Interior Lights<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkRubberising" value="Rubberising" />Rubberising<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkRoofRacks" value="Roof Racks" />Roof racks<br />
```

Now I googled almost two hours and I do not want to waste any more time on this. I've tried everything from

```
 var check = document.getElementById('chkColourCoding');
 if (check.checked)
 {}
```

to

```
 if($("#chkColourCoding").prop('checked'))
 {}
```

and also

```
 if($('.chkColourCoding').is(':checked'))
 {}
```

Can someone please explain to me what is the difference and suggest why something why this is not working? Do I need to do some referencing to use jQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are looking for id and you have not assigned the id to your checkbox.
change this line

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkColourCoding" value="Colour Coding" />
```

to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkColourCoding" value="Colour Coding" id="chkColourCoding" />
```

and your javascript will rock.

Answer (score 1):

`if($("#chkColourCoding").prop('checked')){}`

What you're doing is getting a `DOM` element with `id=chkColourCoding` but it does not exist.

You can either add `id`s to your checkboxes or use `name="theName"`.

```
if($('input[name="chkColourCoding"').is(':checked')){
  //your function
}
```

Comment: Lol...Rookie mistake. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have missed to add id

see below working code...

```
@Html.CheckBox("chkColour")<br />
        <input type="checkbox" id="chkColourCoding" checked
         name="chkColourCoding" value="Colour Coding" />Colour coding<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkDoggyBars" value="Doggy Bars" />Doggy bars<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkLadderRacks" value="Ladder Racks" />Ladder racks<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkCabSliders" value="Cab Sliders" />Cab sliders<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkBrakeLights" value="Brake Lights" />Brake Lights<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkInteriorLights" value="Interior Lights" />Interior Lights<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkRubberising" value="Rubberising" />Rubberising<br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="chkRoofRacks" value="Roof Racks" />Roof racks<br />     


        <script language="javascript">
        var check = document.getElementById('chkColourCoding');
 if (check.checked)
 {
     alert("Checked");
 }
 else
 {
      alert("Not Checked");
 }


        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

inside Views

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="checkbox" />
</div>
```

Inside Script

//check value of

```
var v = $('.checkbox').is(':checked')
        if (v == true)
            alert('true');
        else
            alert('false');
```